# Counting primitives in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I have been reading through the [documentation](http://neo4j.org/doc/) for [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) and it's [components](http://components.neo4j.org/) and have yet to come across functionality that lets me query the total number of primitives (nodes, relationships, and properties) in the graph. Does this functionality exist somewhere or am I going to have to write code that traverses the entire graph counting as it goes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the question! I'm on the Neo4j team, and we currently have commercial tools which report this kind of information. However, an extension of the API is scheduled for the next open source version. For the time being you can use the following non-official API:

```
EmbeddedNeo.getConfig().getNeoModule().getNodeManager().getNumberOfIdsInUse(Class)
```

where the class would be `Node.class`, `Relationship.class` or `PropertyStore.class`.

Comment: Thanks, was very helpful, but shouldn't getNodeModule() be getNeoModule()

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing that out! I updated the code sample.

Comment: This is now documented in the Neo4j FAQ: http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/FAQ#How_can_I_get_the_total_number_of_nodes_and_relationships_currently_in_Neo4j.3F

Comment: ...which has just been updated, because this API tells you the number of IDs allocated, which is not necessarily the same as the number of primitives in use (because IDs need not be contiguous)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PropertyStore

graph.getConfig().getGraphDbModule().getNodeManager().getNumberOfIdsInUse(Node.class);
graph.getConfig().getGraphDbModule().getNodeManager().getNumberOfIdsInUse(Relationship.class);
graph.getConfig().getGraphDbModule().getNodeManager().getNumberOfIdsInUse(PropertyStore.class)
```