# how to calculate average path length in neo4j

Tags: path, neo4j, average

I have 1250000 nodes in neo4j, now I want to calculate the average path length among these nodes. Is there a effective way to do this? If i use: 
for x in nodes:
    for y in nodes:
        cal(x,y)
I think it costs too much time. So I want a more efficient algorithm.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well,
I would duplicate the graph (e.g. in a Neo4j HA cluster) and then run only parts of the total x on each node, that way parallelising the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!I'll have a try

Answer (score 0):

You can try to avoid computing the paths that you already computed in previous steps (somehow like you'd do in dynamic programming). For instance, lets say that you have the path x->y->z, than when computing x--->z path, you'd memorize the paths x->y and y->z so that you can use them later on.

If you use this approach you may hit memory limits, depending on your server configuration.

Comment: It sounds like dijkstra algorithm.For length, I use the API directly,problem is i have to tranvesal the nodes twice to konw the diatance of every pair,it still costs too much.I am not sure whether DP can solve that...

Comment: I'm not sure either but you can give it a try. And yes, you still have  nodes² worst complexity, but you may avoid re-doing some work.

Comment: Thanks!Now I have a problem in getting the largest connected subgraph. I have 1250000 nodes,and I choose the connected and delete the unconnected. After running the program, I delete some nodes, if i use cypher to see the deleted node in the web admin, it says it is an invalid query ,but in the dashboard it still shows i have 1250000 nodes. It seems I haven't deleted nodes at all! Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: What you see in the dashboard is not necessary the number of nodes, but rather the last id. So you should not rely on that numbers. You can look at other responses on this matter, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111252/counting-primitives-in-neo4j

Comment: @user2234995 can you share the code for average path length computation? Thanks