# Count number of primitives in neo4j-server?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to determine if some performance problems are just tuning problems or if I need beefier hardware. Everything I see has some guidelines using a mythical "number of primitives" value. How exactly do I calculate that through the neo4j server though? I don't see anything for it in the Web UI, and I'm not sure if cypher actually exposes the ability to count the number of properties and such.

I've seen this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111252/counting-primitives-in-neo4j), but it appears to be very old with answers pointed to unmaintained links and is referring to the embedded version of the database

How can I calculate the number of primitives in my database through the server interface?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to this page on your browser:

```
http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/info/org.neo4j/Primitive%20count/
```

(Change the host and port, if needed, to point to the actual neo4j server location.)

Comment: Please note that the primitive count in WebAdmin is just a reference number. It's based on the ID counters so if you have been deleting nodes, the number might be actually far off.

Comment: The only way to have an accurate number would be to run a query like "MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)" (# of nodes) or "MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN count(r)" (# of rels) but this might actually take plenty of time if your database is big.